# Django cannot create or save comments

Tags: python, django

I cannot Save comments in django

**my post model is**

```
#model.py

class Post(models.Model):
    thumbnail = models.ImageField()
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    content = HTMLField(null=True)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    featured = models.BooleanField()
    timeStamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    commentCount = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    viewCount = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def absoluteUrl(self):
        return reverse('postContent', kwargs={
            'slug' : self.slug
        })

    @property
    def getComments(self):
        return self.comments.all()
```

**my comment model is**

```
#model.py

class Comment(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    timeStamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    comment = models.TextField()
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**my forms.py is**

```
from .models import Post, Comment

class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control',
        'id' : 'name',
        'placeholder': 'Name'
    }))
    comment = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={
        'class' : 'form-control w-100',
        'id' : 'comment',
        'cols' : '30',
        'rows' : 9,
        'placeholder' : 'Write Comment'
    }))
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('name', 'comment')
```

**my view.py is**

```
from .forms import CommentForm

def post(request, slug):
    categoryCount = getCategoryCount()
    featured = Post.objects.filter(featured=True)
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.post = post
            form.save()
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
    context = {
        'post' : post,
        'featured': featured,
        'categoryCount': categoryCount,
        'form' : form
    }
    return render(request, 'post.html', context)
```

**my post.html is**

```
<div class="comment-form">
    <h4>Leave a Reply</h4>
    <form class="form-contact comment_form" method="POST" action="." id="commentForm">
     {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                {{ form }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="button button-contactForm btn_1 boxed-btn">Send Message</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

**my urls.py**

```
from Posts.views import posts, post, search

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('posts/', posts, name='postLists'),
    path('posts/<slug>', post, name='postContent'),
    path('search/', search, name='search'),
    path('tinymce', include('tinymce.urls')),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I can save comments in admin section but the main problem is when I click the submit button in html the comment is not saving. I am new to django and I cannont figure out the problem.

Is I miss something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
temp = form.save(commit=False)
temp.post = post
temp.save()
```

**Update**

as per @Abdul Aziz Barkat mentioned you have to change your URL in `urls.py` add a trailing slash after `posts/<slug>` and add one more URL to handle `POST` request

for eg.

```
from Posts.views import posts, post, search

urlpatterns = [
    path('posts/<slug>/', post, name='postContent'),
    path('post_comment/<slug>/', post, name='postComment'),
]
```

and than inside your form action add this

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'postComment' post.slug %}">
```

and in your `view.py`

```
def post(request, slug):
```

Comment: Hi!! If I remove action in post.html it is working. But with action it is not working. why it works without action and why it is not working with action in post.html?

Comment: provide your `urls.py` maybe your form is on home page or on `/` root URL and your form `view` is listening `POST` request on `/` URL. When you remove your URL from form action than by default form gives `POST` request to current URL

Comment: I had updated my question with urls.py. Yes Its working on removing action in post.html. Is it correct removing actions in the html?

Comment: no it's not correct but did your data is saved in database ?

Comment: @BadTrickerters8484 an action being `.` means to submit the form to the _current_ directory, since your pattern doesn't have a _trailing_ slash (`posts/<slug>`) hence the current directory is `posts/`. Try adding a trailing slash to your url pattern so it becomes `posts/<slug>/` and it should work properly.

Comment: @Ankit Tiwari Yes the data is saved in the database.

Comment: @Abdul Aziz Barkat After adding trailing slash its worked. Thank You

Comment: Hello @BadTrickerters8484 check my edited answer

Comment: You should put an action to your form because if you want to add two form on the same route so i will not submit or it will throw error

Comment: @AnkitTiwari I had chekecd your updated answer but its raising 404 page not found. Its due to `post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)` in views.py. Action is Working After adding trailing slash in the urls.py

Comment: Hello @BadTrickerters8484 check i have edited my answer